# GraphHopper Dynamic Routing

Tags: graphhopper

I know the question of GH dynamic edge weights has been raised in various forums, but I still find myself lost on how to implement this. I have seen options like - changing the edge weights and recalculating the contracted graph, disabling contraction hierarchies altogether etc. Could someone please explain this to me from a beginners point of view, like where do I begin, which are the available options, drawbacks of each, the packages and classes in the library that are used to achieve this, etc. Thanks

Comment: You have disabled CH and read this: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/weighting.md ?

Comment: Also come back here and create an answer :)